# Bank Accounts Using Vectors (Deposit and Withdrawal)

Tags: c++

I am working on a project that should allow you to create 3 accounts of the form (Name,AccountNumber,Balance) and then gives you the following options:

1) Add an account.

2) Close and existing account.

3) Deposit an amount.

4) Withdraw an account

5) No request.

Up till now, I am able to successfully create 3 accounts, display them, add another account, display them again, delete an account and display them once again. However, I am having trouble figuring out a way to deposit or withdraw money from a specific account.
So to be clear, my question is: How do I access the balance of a chosen account and deposit/withdraw an amount (keeping in mind that I am using vectors to save all accounts)?

The following is my code:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "bank.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

void fillaccounts(vector<bank>&);
void printaccounts(const vector<bank>&);
void createaccount(vector<bank>&);
void depositaccount(vector<bank>&);
void deleteaccount (vector<bank>&);

int main() {

vector<bank> mybank;

fillaccounts(mybank);

for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {

cout << "Please choose one of the following requests: " << endl;
cout << "(1) Create a new account." << endl;
cout << "(2) Close an existing account." << endl;
cout << "(3) Deposit an amount in one of your accounts." << endl;
cout << "(4) Withdraw an amount from one of your accounts." << endl;
cout << "(5) No request." << endl;
cout << "Enter your choice here: " << endl;

int request;
cin >> request;

switch (request) {
    case 1:
        createaccount(mybank);
        printaccounts(mybank);
        break;

    case 2:

        deleteaccount(mybank);
        printaccounts(mybank);
        break;

    case 3:

        depositaccount(mybank);
        printaccounts(mybank);
        break;

    case 4:

        break;

    case 5:

        break;

}
}
}


void fillaccounts(vector<bank>& newmybank) {

string name;
int accountnumber;
double balance;

for (int i=0; i<3;i++) {
    cout << "Enter your first name: " << endl;
    cin >> name;

    cout << "Enter account number: " << endl;
    cin >> accountnumber;

    cout << "Enter the amount you want to deposit: " << endl;
    cin >> balance;

    bank newAccount(name, accountnumber,balance);
    newmybank.push_back(newAccount);
    cout << endl;
}
cout << endl;

}

void createaccount(vector<bank>& newmybank) {

string name;
int accountnumber;
double balance;

    cout << "Enter your first name: " << endl;
    cin >> name;

    cout << "Enter account number: " << endl;
    cin >> accountnumber;

    cout << "Enter the amount you want to deposit: " << endl;
    cin >> balance;

    bank newAccount(name,accountnumber,balance);
    newmybank.push_back(newAccount);
    cout << endl;

}


void printaccounts(const vector<bank>& newmybank) {

for (unsigned int i=0; i<newmybank.size();i++) {

    cout << "(" << newmybank[i].getname() << "," <<    newmybank[i].getaccountnumber() << "," << newmybank[i].getbalance() << ")" << endl;

}
cout << endl;
}


void deleteaccount(vector<bank>& newmybank) {

string name;

cout << "Please enter your name to delete your account: " << endl;
cin >> name;
cout << endl;

for (int i=0; i<newmybank.size(); i++) {

    if (newmybank[i].newname == name) {

        newmybank.erase(newmybank.begin()+i);

    }
}
}
```

Bank.cpp

```
#include "Bank.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

bank::bank() {

newname=' ';
newaccountnumber=0;
newbalance=0.0;
}

bank::bank(string name,int accnum,double amount) {
newname=name;
newaccountnumber=accnum;
newbalance=amount;
}

string bank::getname() const {
return newname;
}

int bank::getaccountnumber() const {
return newaccountnumber;
}

double bank::getbalance() const {
return newbalance;
}

void bank::setname(string name) {
newname=name;
}

void bank::setaccountnumber(int accountnumber) {
newaccountnumber=accountnumber;
}

void bank::setbalance(double balance) {
newbalance=balance;
}
```

Bank.hpp

```
class bank {


public:

string newname;
int newaccountnumber;
double newbalance;

bank(); //Constructor

bank(string,int,double); //Overload Constructor

string getname() const;
int getaccountnumber() const;
double getbalance() const;
void setname(string);
void setaccountnumber(int);
void setbalance(double);

};
```

Any advice on how to follow up?
Thank you guys!

Comment: Shouldn't have a `bank` multiple accounts? It just looks like you're going to manage a `bank` instance for each account. That looks pretty unuseful, you designe is flawed from the bones IMHO.

Comment: Deja-vu from, I think, yesterday:(

Comment: It is for a project. I just need to start by figuring out this first code and all that is left is the deposit and withdrawal part of it. Do you have any idea how to help me out in this particular situation? I did some research but I could not find how modify the balance in an account.

Comment: You have a `setbalance` and a `getbalance` method.  Use them.  Or, modify the bank class to allow adding a balance, similar to how those work.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to add a function to your bank class which adds a specific amount to the account balance and then call this method when you want to change the account value (i.e. to deposit/withdraw), or create 2 separate methods.

Something like:

```
void bank::deposit(int num)
{
    newbalance += num;
}
```

You would then have a user specify a bank account number (or name), because I don't think you would want to change every balance from every account. A function `getAccountIndex` might loop through every account to find the specified data, then return the index in your vector.

When you have the index you can invoke the `deposit` method like so `mybank[index].deposit(amount);`

*Note that your variables in the `bank` class are public, so you don't really need get/set methods, but this is considered bad practice so you should make those variables private.*

Comment: I have another question @BlitzRakete! I realized that when I output the value of newbalance, it always gives 0. Therefore i'm always adding the inputted deposit value to 0 and not to the actual value in the account. How do I link them together??
Thanks again!

Comment: @Jaaadeee They are already linked together, because they are in the same class. `depositaccount` doesn't have an implementation, you should check that if you haven't already.